Show that a bounded, monotone increasing sequence converges
I am attempting to show if $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ is a bounded, monotone increasing sequence of real numbers, then $x_n$ is convergent to the supremum. Here is my proof, but I believe I have not done it correctly
Let $S = \{ x_n : n \in \mathbb N\}$. As $S$ is bounded, there exists $x^* \in \mathbb R$ such that $x^*$ is the supremum of $S$.
Let $x_n = x^* - \frac1n$, and choose $\epsilon > 0$. Then for all $N > n$, with $n,N \in \mathbb N$, $|x^* - x_n| = |\frac1n| < \epsilon$.
Choose $\epsilon = \frac1n$. Then $\frac1N < \frac1n = \epsilon$, hence $x_n$ converges to $x^*$.
My thought is that I have only shown that the sequence $x^* - \frac1n$ converges to $x^*$, and not a general $x_n$. If so, what would I need to modify in order to show any bounded monotone increasing sequence converges to the supremum. Any feedback is much appreciated!

You're right, you only proved that $(x^*-1/n)$ converges to $x^*$. In general, if $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N\geqslant 0$ such that $x_N>x^*-\varepsilon$ by the properties of the supremum. Since $(x_n)$ is increasing, you have $x_n\geqslant x_N>x^*-\varepsilon$ for all $n\geqslant N$, since we also have $x_n<x^*+\varepsilon$ for all $n\geqslant 0$ (try to see why) then $|x_n-x^*|<\varepsilon$ for all $n\geqslant N$ and we're done.

Aaah I thought so. Your explanation makes sense, thank you for helping!
